# Secure Arduino over internet

Tags: automation, arduino

I am trying to create a system for controlling my home appliances using arduino over internet.
Arduino Uno will act as a web server and recieve the commands from remote browser.

In doing to I am not sure as how to protect arduino from unauthorized requests from web.
Is there a way to do this, or is there any library available for this. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

What i suggest you is to do what a lot of people does, so: use a raspberry (or a beaglebone or another linux embedded board) for the web interface and the arduino for the sensors/actuators.

This way you can install a real webserver, with a lot more functionalities than the bare arduino. You can then interface the webpages to the serial port to send the arduino the commands